# How to lookup multiple sub-values of

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I have a list of ID which each Type header has 3 sub-headers A, B, C. Now I need to find the value of  sub-headers of specific ID and Type.

Example sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GIHMTa-wSxHb6x9lZbn0mwAl0Mh7Xdk6XneIgw5Y6x0/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `OFFSET` and `MATCH`:

```
=OFFSET(F1, MATCH(B2, F:F, 0) - 1, MATCH(C2, F1:1, 0) - 1, 1, 3)
```

[image]